# Visual Studio 2010 - cannot reconnect to SQL Server instance after project is saved

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Using Visual Studio 2010 I am able to start a new project using ADODB (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library  COM  6.1.0.0) to connect to MS Access and SQL Server, save the project, re-open the project and it all works as expected.  BUT when I do this trying to connect to a SQL Server Instance it will work until I save the project after which I always get the error: "SQL Server does not exist or access denied".

Here is the code for my test console application;

```vb
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()
    Dim cnStr As String
    ' Modify this connection string to reflect your server and logon information.
    ' Store the connection to a variable to be used throughout this example.
    cnStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=Firehouse;Data Source=devclstr\devclstr;" & _
       "User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"
    ' 1. Connect through the Connectionstring property.
    cn.ConnectionString = cnStr
    cn.Open()
    rs.Open("select * from usr_sec", cn)
    Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, rs, "products")
    Console.Write("There are " & ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString & " total users.")
    Console.ReadLine()
    rs = Nothing
    cn.Close()
    cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

End Module

This will work only in the following scenario: start new console project, enter the code, add the "ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" reference, and it runs as expected.  As soon as I save it each subsequent execution gives me the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259
>   HResult=-2147467259
>   Message=[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
>   Source=Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
>   StackTrace: at ADODB._Connection.Open(String ConnectionString, String UserID, String Password, Int32 Options)

Please share any insight in how to resolve this problem

Comment: Why aren't you using either the built in `SqlConnection` or even `OledbConnection`?

Comment: I've tried all 3 methods and get the same results, the code above just shows the last version.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I'd advise against using the COM approach, when there are built in connectors, so instead, something like:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient;

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Modify this connection string to reflect your server and logon information.
        Dim cnStr As String = "Initial Catalog=Firehouse;Data Source=devclstr\devclstr;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"

        Using con as New SqlConnection(cnStr)
            con.Open()

            Using cmd as New SqlCommand("select * from usr_sec", con)
                Using da As New SqlDbDataAdapter()
                    Dim ds As New DataSet()
                    da.Fill(ds, rs, "products")
                    Console.Write(String.Format("There are {0} total users.", ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count))
                    Console.ReadLine()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know tomorrow.

Comment: I'm getting the same results ,,SQLClient version. I was able to enter the code and run it successfully but after I saved the project I'm back to the same error. Error message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: With the help of a friend we stumbled across the problem. I've been using a network drive for development; my friend suggested I save a new test example on my C: drive when we noticed that it worked both before and after saving it as a VS Project. I copied over my original, more extensive test example to my local C: drive, this code has variety of ways to “break”;  every example ran.
There must be subtle differences in how MS Visual Studio builds/debugs/etc  when using a network driver versus a local drive.
Has anybody else ran into this situation and does anyone how to fix it?

Comment: I wanted to share my latest test results
 
I copied the network share version .exe of the program failing to connect to SQL Server Instance to my C: drive, double clicked it, it ran and connected to the SQL Server Instance. Then, to be sure I double clicked the original back on the network share, it failed to connect to the SQL Server Instance. This is not a Visual Studio problem.
 
There must be a setting somewhere in Windows 7 Pro w/SP1 32-bit on my PC that prevents executables running from my network share drive to connect to an SQL Server Instance. Does anyone have a clue of where to look?